# Set cell links in a datagridview with datasource from dataTable

Tags: vb.net, datagridview, hyperlink

I have DataGridView in which I need to set links in some cells (not in a single column). All cells (columns) are of `DataGridViewTextBoxCell` type.

When I populate the DGV from a DataTable (`.DataSource = dataTable`) links do not show.
However, if I populate the DGV from an array (`.DataSource = Nothing`) links are shown and work.

In both cases I use the following code `row.Cells("detailsID") = New DataGridViewLinkCell`.
I tried adding an extra column (`Dim links As New DataGridViewLinkColumn()`, just for the links), but this approach doesn't work either.

Any ideas what could be the problem?

**EDIT**

I solved the problem by building the DGV before parent form is shown (in the form_load event)! The old solution was build the DGV, and then show the form.

Comment: Why didn’t the `DataGridViewLinkColumn` work for you? If the underlying data column for the links column is a `string` type column, then it should work with a grids link column. Granted you have to manually set the link column in the grid, and set its `DataProperty` name to mate with the underlying data source link column name… then wire-up the grids `CellContentClick` to launch the url. I am just saying that a link column should work. You didn’t say “why” the link column didn’t work for you so… maybe I am missing something.

Comment: *Any ideas what could be the problem?* - the chief problem is a lack of info in the question - "didn't work" isn't a bug report we can do anything with, Post the code that "didn't work" and say what "didn't work" means, so that we can have a go at reproducing the problem on our own machines

Comment: @JohnG thanks for your comment that made me revisit and rethink the approach. For reasons not known even to me (perhaps because I worked on a very old, and simple procedure), I was building the DGV before the parent form was loaded. I switched the order (build the DGV in the form_load event) and now everything works fine. I'm still puzzled why it worked when `DGV.DataSource=Nothing`, but it doesn't matter since I used wrong approach.

Comment: @CaiusJard you are right that I didn't provide much info, but I was trying not to bother with lots of code, and hoped that there was a simple solution. Thanks for your comment.